# Smoke Simulation Breaks Apart

Tags: smoke-simulation

I have been having a problem with a smoke simulation that falls apart after about 60 frames, and I can't for the life of me figure out why. For the first part of the simulation the smoke looks as I would expect but then it falls apart. The smoke is being produced from a particle emitter set to produce 1500 particles for 15 frames. It is for a train smoke simulation, and the domain is parented to an empty that the train is also parented to and begins to move at the time the simulation starts.

There are wind force fields - turbulence and wind. But removing the turbulence made no difference. I've done everything I can think of - including using a single emitter which actually was worse. It looks like there is an animated force field - something I definitely didn't do deliberately and cannot find anywhere anyway.

I just can't understand why it breaks apart the way it does. Note the screen grabs...the first picture shows what the simulation looks like just a few frames after the one on the right.

Has anyone seen this before? Can illuminate?[image: Smoke Simulation Breaking Apart]

Answer (score 0):

Select the emitter object and in the smoke physics tab turn up the Sample Sub-steps. That may help.

What I did when I was experiencing this issue is select the domain and in the domain physics tab under 'Field Weights' I turned off every field except for the one in my scene (which was only a turbulence field that was parented to the emitter object)

Hope this helps. :-)

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment and the tips. In the end the problem was that the domain border was too close to the emitter. It was as simple as that. I was trying to maximise resolution for the area that the smoke was modelling and the border was close to the chimney stack.